# Open C# Winforms app through associated file clicking

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a small app that accepts two different types of files (*.miz and *.5js). There are two functions that do parse those files, and they already work properly when triggered from button click events (see below). Also, the solution contains this project and a setup project, to create the installer of the app.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Load mission file";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        textBox4.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        processMizFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        button1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
```

and

```
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button6.BackColor = Color.Red;

        openFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = "";
        openFileDialog2.Title = "Load standalone Datacards";
        openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();

        loadDatacard(openFileDialog2.FileName);

        button6.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
```

I am now trying to call those functions when I start the app by double clicking in one of those file types (associated to my app through Windows properties dialog). For that, I am running the following code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        LoadFont();
        InitializeComponent();


        string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();//to display program version in the form
        label29.Text += version;

        string[] cmdl = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\log.txt"))
        {
            if (cmdl.Length > 1)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Argument 0 - Exe path: " + cmdl[0]);
                sw.WriteLine("Argument 1: " + cmdl[1]);
                sw.WriteLine("File type: " + Path.GetExtension(cmdl[1]).ToUpper());
            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Argument 0 - Exe path: " + cmdl[0]);
                sw.WriteLine("No further arguments provided");
            }
        }

        if (cmdl.Length > 1)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(cmdl[1]).ToUpper() == ".MIZ")
            {
                processMizFile(cmdl[1]);
                using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.CreateText(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\log2.txt"))
                {
                    sw2.WriteLine("MIZ file loaded!");
                }
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(cmdl[1]).ToUpper() == ".5JS")
            {
                loadDatacard(cmdl[1]);
                using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.CreateText(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\log2.txt"))
                {
                    sw2.WriteLine("5Js file loaded!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The streamwriter parts are in place to have some traces, as I am not sure how can I debug this, otherwise.

Now, the problem is that it all works properly on the same laptop where I have Visual Studio installed. But, it does not work on a different computer:

1. Release Build

   - If I just double click one of the associated files(on the Desktop), the splash screen flashes quickly, and goes away. No log file is written
   - If I double click an associated file in the same path as the installed executable, it works fine
   - If I launch the app from command line, passing a path as argument, I get:

   `log.txt:
   Argument 0 - Exe path: DatacardGenerator.exe
   Argument 1: C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Desktop\Datacards.5js
   File type: .5JS`

log3.txt: writes up to "Created path to extract dir: " and the right Appdata folder to temporary extract

---

```
using (StreamWriter sw3 = File.AppendText(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\log3.txt"))
        {
            sw3.WriteLine("Created path to extract dir: " + extract5Js);
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(extract5Js))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(extract5Js, true);
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw3 = File.AppendText(Application.UserAppDataPath + @"\log3.txt"))
        {
            sw3.WriteLine("Proceeding to unzip...");
        }
        
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(path5jscard, extract5Js);
```

So, how could I know what happens during the startup of my app when launched by an external file? I`ve set command line arguments in debug mode to test, but I am not sure if they come with full path or not, given the different results on the target machine (works if files in same directory as exe, does not work otherwise)

Thanks for the support!! :)

P.S: I do not process the command line arguments directly in Main() because I am using 2 different forms: Form2 is a splash screen, and Form1 is the main program. For that I am using an example I found time ago, in this way:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2{    
static class Program{
    static private List<PrivateFontCollection> _fontCollections;
    

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);

        CultureInfo culture;
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;


        //Dispose all used PrivateFontCollections when exiting
        Application.ApplicationExit += delegate {
            if (_fontCollections != null)
            {
                foreach (var fc in _fontCollections) if (fc != null) fc.Dispose();
                _fontCollections = null;
            }
            string appPath = Application.UserAppDataPath;
            string parentPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(appPath).ToString();
            
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(parentPath, true);
        };

        //Application.Run(new Form1());
        new MyApp().Run(args);
    }

}
public class MyApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    
    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        this.SplashScreen = new Form2();
    }
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        // Do your initialization here
        //...
        // Then create the main form, the splash screen will automatically close
        this.MainForm = new Form1();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For better traces use a logging framework. I have been using NLog, Log4Net and others. They may have different sets of features and performance and so on, but in your case, any of them will probably simplify things _a lot_.

Comment: Does your installer correctly register the file extensions with your app?

Comment: You need to publish and install application on remote machine.   Publish creates a serup.exe folder like commercial software.  For a Net application to work on a remote machine either you need same version of Net installed on Build and Deplay machines or you have to publish.  Not all machine have same versions of windows dlls and running setup.exe updates the windows dlls on deploy machine to be compatible with the build machine.

Comment: @jdweng: I have created a setup project, so I am creating an installer, which also updates the .NET framework to the required version (4.8, in this case).It is a Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project

Comment: @Fildor: that could be it, but how should I register the extensions with the installer? My only step was to go to one of the files in Windows, right-click-->Properties-->"Opens with"-->change and point to the EXE

Comment: Ok, I just looked it up and registered the two types of files with my Setup Project (View - File types - Add). Then build the release, and tried. Still the same: it works if the file is copied into the root folder of the app, it does not work if I trigger it from a file somewhere else

Comment: This looks weird:
- If I double click in the Desktop file (Datacards.5js), the splash screen flashes and the app closes without throwing any exception
- If I launch the program from command line:
c:\Program Files (x86)\GV5Js\GV5JsDatacardGenerator>DatacardGenerator.exe C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Desktop\Datacards.5js
then, it works

I am wondering if the commandline argument passed when double clicking looks in any way different than the one I write in command line, although it should not...

Comment: I have tried putting Datacards.5js directly in C:\ 

- 2x click in C:\Datacards.5js shows splash screen (Form2) and closes w/o exception, and w/o writing log file
- c:\Program Files (x86)\GV5Js\GV5JsDatacardGenerator>DatacardGenerator.exe C:\Datacards.5js works flawlessly, and writes all the log files

Is there any format of the arguments I might be missing? quotes, backslashes... 
IDK how to debug when starting from external file. If I set the cmd line argument as debug option, it will work: I am setting what the app expects. And IDK how to debug if I am starting the app from outside VS

Comment: Program File folder usually admins only have write permission.  Also when running from VS you do not have Admin rights unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The default folder when running a Net application is the same folder where the exe is located.  Also the c:\ root folder on most machines only admins have write priviledge.

Comment: @jdweng I was launching from an admin account. I even tried to execute as admin the app... it is still the same. I am trying to trim quotes, and maybe something with the backslash characters... but running out of ideas :(

Comment: Ok, narrowing down... after adding a cmdl[1].Trim(´"´); statement, I get it to work from commandline, like:
C:\Program Files (x86)\GV5Js\GV5JsDatacardGenerator> DatacardGenerator.exe c:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Datacards.5js WORKS!!!
But if I just double click the same file, the app launches and closes without throwing exception.

Conclusion: there must be a difference between the argument passed to the app by double-click and adding it manually like above from the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I just had to declare a global var in Main to be accessed from my form, like:

```
public static string[] cmdlArgs;
    

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);

        CultureInfo culture;
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        cmdlArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

And then it can be accessed using the namespace :

```
Program.cmdlArgs
```